# Regex for substring like "value1...valueN":"$SpecifcWord"

Tags: regex

I have a long string with some HTML data in which I need to find this pattern:

```
"AnyWord1 ... AnyWordN":"$SpecificWord"
```

There is must be any number of AnyWordN words, but after it is always only one word "$SpecificWord"

I tried

```
\".*\"\$SpecifcWord\"
```

but this only work, when there is no quotation mark symbols in data before first " before "AnyWord"

So it works for this example: http://regexr.com?32kqh

But didn't work if text before this pattern containt other quotation mark, like this: http://regexr.com?32kqk

I'm sure, that there is no " characters in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question (what is "value1", and what do you mean by `" symbol near value1`?), but in general, your regex should be matching correctly, if the source code of the page you're looking at really contains exactly this text.

To cover a few corner cases, it might be worth making some parts of the regex more explicit:

```
var myregex = /"[^"]*":"\$SpecificWord"/
```

might work better.

Another potential problem: Are you certain that you have actual `"` characters in your string? Or might they be in fact `&quot;` character entities?

Please clarify your question.